# Number as proverb

Tags: expressions

I see that some numbers in the following conversation appeared standalone maybe as a proverb. Can they be explained grammatically?

> Raj: Okay. Well, a couple of things. Don't tell them I come from money. I want them to love me for me. They must be insanely hot. Like nines or tens.
>       Penny: Nines or tens?
>       Raj: Okay, an eight is acceptable if she's willing to bring another eight to the hot tub.
>       Bernadette: Bottom line, you'll take any woman who'll have you, right?
>       Raj: In a New Delhi minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just very common in America to rate things on a scale of 1 to 10, so if you say, "I rate this a 6" without specifying a scale, most people will assume you mean a scale of 1 to 10. There's a common joke based on this: You say, "I rate this a 9." And the listeners think you are rating it very high, 9 out of 10. Then you add, "On a scale of 1 to 1000."

As @JackOFlaherty says, men will sometimes rate women's desirability on a scale of 1 to 10, where "10" means she's beautiful, sexy, funny, whatever you think makes a woman desirable, and "1" means ugly, boring, etc. There was a movie a few years ago (okay, when I check I see it was 1979) called "10", about a man who meets a woman whom he considers a 10. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078721/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1 (I haven't seen the movie, I just remembered the title as appropriate here, so I can't comment whether it's any good.)

So Raj starts out saying he wants women who are 9's or 10's -- women who are the top of the scale of desirability. When Penny pushes him on this, he says okay, he'll also accept 8's. She pushes a little more and he concedes that he'll settle for anyone who will have him.

Because for a man to win a woman who's a 10, presumably he has to score pretty high on the scale that women use to rate men. And maybe Raj realizes he's not a 10 himself.

Comment: Thanks, Jay, so is the scale something most American know even without watching that movie?

Comment: Yes. The people who made the movie didn't invent the idea of the scale, it was around long before that movie. I really don't know how long the idea of that scale has been around or who invented it. Perhaps I should add that rating things on a scale from 1 to 10 is pretty common in America. If you said, "Hey, I rate this car a 9!", most Americans would instantly assume that you mean on a scale of 1 to 10. So it was probably inevitable that sooner or later someone would apply the scale to women.

Comment: My question here is in fact about the numbers, not the provided example context.  So do you mean when the numbers below then are used as nouns they, they are used as a pronoun for a subject that is graded between 1 to 10? Can it be extended to larger numbers? e.g. 25 can be something that is graded between 1 to 100?

Comment: Only if the scale is established and agreed upon in context. If everyone involved knows you're talking about a 100-point scale, "that's a 25" is meaningful, but people wouldn't automatically guess that out of context.

Comment: You could invent a scale with any numbers. There's nothing stopping you from saying, I'm going to rate X on a scale from 7 to 38. What I'm saying is, it's just very common in America to rate things on a scale of 1 to 10, so if you say, "I rate this a 6" without specifying a scale, most people will assume you mean a scale of 1 to 10. There's a common joke based on this: You say, "I rate this a 9." And the listeners think you are rating it very high, 9 out of 10. Then you add, "On a scale of 1 to 1000."

Comment: And note I'm talking here about an arbitrary scale. If you are measuring a length, you might say "It's 8 centimeters." That's not on a scale of 1 to 10, that's a measurement with no upper bound. (Short of the Hubble limit for the size of the universe, anyway.) I always cringe a little when TV reporters talk about the magnitude of an earthquake, because they always say "on the open-ended Richter scale". Well, yeah, the Richter scale is "open ended". It's a measurement. It's like saying, "That's 20 kilometers from here, on the open-ended metric distance scale." :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's a reference to a crass way of rating women by their sexual desirability, on a scale of one to ten.